# How to update view when loading data to model in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several `<selects>` that get updated every time an object property on the module changes value. The problem comes when I try to remember state. I save every change to `localStorage`, but when I reasign the saved object on window reload, the model changes correctly but the view doesn't show the change unless I click on a `<select>`, and then is when all the others that are supposed to be selected get their real values from the model.

I can see that this happens when the load is delayed with a timeout or a event listener.

How can i fix this?

```js
var my_app = angular.module('campaign_listing', [])
  .controller('campaign_list_controller', campaign_list_controller);

function campaign_list_controller($http) {
  var este = this;
  this.filters = {
    categories: ["a"],
  };

  function get_save_state() {
    var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("filters"));
    return items;
  }
  this.recover_state = function() {

    var save = get_save_state();
    console.log("recovering state:")
    if (save) this.filters = save;

  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    este.recover_state();
  }, 300);
}
```

```html
<select 
        id="multiselect_categories" 
        name="categories" 
        ng-model="ctrl.filters.categories" 
        ng-change="ctrl.update_fields()" 
        multiple="multiple">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How are you binding the model to the view? Show us some code, because it should auto-refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use angular's $timeout instead of setTimeout, this will force a new digest cycle that will update the UI

```
$timeout(function() {
    este.recover_state();
  }, 300);
```